# Xcode Swift: Error using a framework that uses a pod (CocoaPods)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have made a Swift framework that uses a pod (SCrypto). I could build the framework and the host project with no errors.

But when I run the iPhone simulator (from the project that uses the framework) I get the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SCrypto.framework/SCrypto
>
> Referenced from: ...
>
> Reason: image not found

I'd be very thankful if someone helped me with this problem.

**Details:**

Have tried clean and build, didn't work.

Both the project and the framework are in Swift, meant for iOS. I'm using the latest versions of Swift and Xcode.

My pod file includes `use_frameworks!`. I have not run 'pot init' in the directory of my project - just in the directory of the framework.

In the build phases of the project, the framework is listed under Link Binary with Libraries.

*There are some other pages on stack overflow about this error, but the solutions there are outdated or didn't work for me. It doesn't let me comment on those (to say that it didn't work for me). Some of the other ones seem to complicated for a simple thing (using a framework that uses a pod), which make me doubt if they would work. Again, I can't comment there and ask this. So I have to use this page instead.*

Comment: what are you running after pod installation ? I mean Xproj or Workspace ?

Comment: So your library is also a pod itself? How do you use your Library?

Comment: UmairAfzal: workspace. Problem is in the project that uses the framework that uses the pod (SCrypto). Framework itself builds successfully.

Prine: no and it's not a library. it's a framework. Dragged the framework's project file into the hosting project

Comment: Try updating CocoaPods. 'sudo gem install cocoapods'

Comment: have done that about 2 hours ago

Comment: I have not run `pod init` in the directory of my project - just in the directory of the framework. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run pod init in the directory of your project so that when you run pod install it will install it to your project, then close everything after installation and open again your project , only this time use yourprojectname.xcsworkspace. be sure it's not yourprojectname.xcodeproject or it will give you No such module error

Comment: Did that. Now I get: "Cannot load underlying module for 'SCrypto'"

Comment: That usually happens, but after you build the project it will automatically go away. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: yes i get the error when i build. tried clean and build also, didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried cmd+shift+K? Also try right click the SCrypto resources folder and search for module and drag it to your project.

Comment: I mean the bundle

Comment: Somehow it now builds successfully. But when i run the iPhone simulator I get this error: "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SCrypto.framework/SCrypto ... Reason: image not found". Looked at some stack overflow pages about this. Either outdated or didn't work for me. The website didn't let me comment there. Should it be so hard to use a framework that uses pods - or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it means, image does not exist. Just delete the image in the path so it wont call it when app starts. Also can you accept my answer? We did remove all the errors anyway right :)

Comment: where can i find the image? and what's it's name?

Comment: Build Phases -> Compile Resources - remove the image  name string, also can you give me the complete sentence for this @rpath/SCrypto.framework/SCrypto...

Comment: and please click check button cuz we have already resolved the original problem

Comment: The image is not there. Thanks a lot for your time but it didn't get solved through your suggestion (i got a different error: 'cannot load underlying module...'). Now I have just included the framework in the project. The "..." is the next sentence (see my question's body). I don't get why I should install pods in the project directory - it's already installed for the framework's directory.